# Como transformar um array simples em .csv?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um Array simples que é gerado com números aleatórios

```js
function gerarNumeros() {
  //Defina aqui a quantidade de numeros que serão gerados
  let quantidadeNumeros = document.getElementById("quantidadenumeros").value

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  let arrayNumeros = []
  let contador = 1

  while (contador <= quantidadeNumeros) {
    //Gera um numero de 6 digitos
    let numero = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)

    //Se o numero aleoatóio NÃO está no array, adiciona ele e continua com o while, senão, gera outro
    if (!arrayNumeros.includes(numero)) {
      arrayNumeros.push(numero)
      contador++
    }
  }

  console.log(arrayNumeros)


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Digite a Quantidade de Números para gerar:
</h3>
<input type="number" id="quantidadenumeros"><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="gerarNumeros();" id="botaoDownload" value="Download CSV">
```

(Código: https://jsfiddle.net/1pfgnb78/3/ )

Exemplo de array:

[223452, 754168, 816518, 826338, 357144, 163946]

Como eu desejo que ele fique no arquivo .csv:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, coloque o código na pergunta e não o link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para transformar uma array no formato que queres basta uma linha:

```
const conteudo = arr.map((nr, i) => `${i+1},${nr}`).join('\n');
```

Se estiveres a fazer isso no servidor com Node.js tens de enviar o ficheiro para o cliente. Se fizeres em JavaScript podes usar diretamente `data:application/octet-stream` no `href` de um `<a>`. Dá para usar o botão para gerar a tabela e gerar um clique no `<a>` que dispara no browser o comportamento pretendido. Com o atributo `download` podes até dar um nome ao ficheiro...

Testei no Chrome e faz o que procuras, não testei noutros browsers mas o JavaScript que indiquei em cima funciona em todos os browsers modernos.

```js
function gerarNumeros() {
  const quantidadeNumeros = Number(document.getElementById("quantidadenumeros").value);
  const arrayNumeros = []
  while (arrayNumeros.length <= quantidadeNumeros) {
    const numero = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
    if (!arrayNumeros.includes(numero)) {
      arrayNumeros.push(numero)
    }
  }
  return arrayNumeros;
}

function gerarCSV() {
  const arr = gerarNumeros();
  const conteudo = arr.map((nr, i) => `${i+1},${nr}`).join('\n');
  const data = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(conteudo);
  const a = document.querySelector('a');
  a.href = data;
  a.click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Digite a Quantidade de Números para gerar:
</h3>
<input type="number" id="quantidadenumeros"><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="gerarCSV();" value="Download CSV">

<a style="display: none;" href="" download="tabela.csv"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

arrayfinal = replaceAll(arrayNumeros.toString(), ",", "\n")

console.log(arrayfinal)
```

Depois:

```
~/$ node app.js > codigos.csv
```